# put and change the place of the player in pacman in C

Tags: c

I'm creating a function that places the player randomly and another function that updates his place. I'm using another function valide(); to verify that the case is available to move (not a wall ..etc).

I'm having a problem when updating a player's position..

This is the function that will place the player randomly it doesn't work either.

```
joueur_t* placer_j(int** pl)
{
  joueur_t* joueur= NULL;
  joueur->name='J';
  // pl = plateau .. the table of pacman
  //joueur = player 

  joueur->x=rand() % P_SIZE+15; // P_SIZE +15 = WIDTH WALL =30
  joueur->y=rand() % P_SIZE; //y P_SIZE HEIGHT =15

  // a voir si la case est vide pour placer un joueur en utilisent la function valide();

  if (valide(pl, joueur->x,joueur->y=='4'))
  {
    pl[joueur->x][joueur->y]=joueur->name;

    return joueur;
  }
}
```

This one is for updating the position I couldn't even start..

```
void update_j(int** pl, joueur_t* jou)
{


}
```

valid function( if there's no wall the player can move otherwise no)

```
int valide(int** pl, int i, int j) // if the case is empty then the player can move
{
  for (i = 0; i <P_SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < P_SIZE+15; j++)
    {
      if ((pl[i][j] == 2)) // 2 = WALL
      {
        return 0;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  }
}
```

So i need help with my function update_j when a player take a move (i'm using WASD keys) i need to update his position with the new location.

I would be thankful for some advice.

Thank you

Comment: We are going to have to see the valide function and more code in order to help you.  Also, can you add some more details to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (valide(pl, joueur->x,joueur->y=='4'))
  {
    pl[joueur->x][joueur->y]=joueur->name;

    return joueur;
  }
}
```

The function rand() returns an integer type.

```
joueur->y=='4'
```

Checks whether the y position of the player is equal to character '4' which corresponds to int value 52.
In addition, by using the binary operator '==' you are passing to the function valide()

```
int valide(int** pl, int i, int j)
```

a binary result (0 or 1) as its third argument. As far as I understand that is meant to be the y position of the player.